# RestTemplate custom ResponseErrorHandler to catch api service real message

Tags: java, spring-boot, error-handling, resttemplate

I am mapping an application that in the case of parameter errors returns a (different) message that always has the following structure:

```
{
  "error": true,
  "reason": "No data is available for this location"
}
```

I am trying to implement a custom `ResponseErrorHandler` for the `RestTemplate` that intercepts this message and then reads an error handling (e.g., using Logs). The problem is that I do not understand how to extract from the `httpResponse` object of `ClientHttpResponse`, in the `handleError` method, the previous message:

```
public class OpenMeteoResponseErrorHandler implements ResponseErrorHandler {
    @Override
    public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse httpResponse)
            throws IOException {
        return httpResponse.getStatusCode().is4xxClientError()
                || httpResponse.getStatusCode().is5xxServerError();
    }

    @Override
    public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse httpResponse)
            throws IOException {
        if(httpResponse.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE){
            throw new ServiceUnAvailableException("Service is currently unavailable");
        } else if (httpResponse.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST) {
            throw new BadRequestException("Bad request");
        }
    }
}
```

**note**,

```
System.out.println(httpResponse.getBody());
```

returns:

```
 sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@79821fea
```

where:

```
public class BadRequestException extends RuntimeException{

    public BadRequestException(){
        super();
    }

    public BadRequestException(String message){
        super(message);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class ServiceUnAvailableException extends RuntimeException{

    public ServiceUnAvailableException() {
        super();
    }
    public ServiceUnAvailableException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

lastly:

```
@Configuration
public class RestTemplateWithErrorHandlerConfig {

    @Bean
    RestTemplate restTemplateWithErrorHandler(){
        return new RestTemplateBuilder()
                .errorHandler(new OpenMeteoResponseErrorHandler())
                .build();
    }
}
```

This is to intercept the possible error in the case of the RestTemplate within the @controller of Spring Boot:

```
Collection<String> queryStringValues = apiQueryMap.values();
try {
    List<ForecastDataDocument> resultDocuments = queryStringValues.stream().map(query -> restTemplateWithErrorHandler.getForObject(query, ForecastWeatherDataDTO.class)).map(dto -> modelMapper.map(dto, ForecastDataDocument.class)).toList();
    forecastDataService.saveForecastData(resultDocuments);
} catch (BadRequestException | ServiceUnAvailableException ex) {
  System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```